# Xcode: "no debug symbols in executable" for repeated Release build with Deployment Postprocessing

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, dsym, dsymutil

#### The Problem

When I repeatedly build release in Xcode, the resulting dSYM is completely empty and so the debugger can't show anything.

I've been able to reproduce this with a minimal project as follows in **Xcode 11.3.1**:

- File -> New Project (macOS, App, Objective-C)
- in the target's *Build Settings*:

  - set the `DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING` for `Release` to `YES`
- Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme

  - set `Build Configuration` to `Release`
- Product -> Build
- change a file that's not being compiled into the binary (e.g. change the *Copyright* notice in `Info.plist`
- Product -> Build

Now there is a warning in the build log in the *GenerateDSYMFile* step

```
warning: no debug symbols in executable (-arch x86_64)
```

If the resulting app is run, there will be no debug information (you can't set a breakpoint in Xcode, if you break manually the stack frames will just be `___lldb_unnamed_symbol`, ...)

#### What I found out so far

The relevant part of the Xcode build process seems to be:

1. Linking the object files to form the binary (only if at least one of them has changed)
2. Generate dSYM file from binary (if anything in the output has changed)
3. Stripping the binary, i.e. removing debug symbols (if anything in the output has changed)

So 1) is skipped in the repeated build, because the sources (and thus the object files) have not changed. 2) is executed, because the `Info.plist` has changed, but it operates on the binary that has already been stripped by the previous build. Hence, the dSYM is empty.

It looks like 2) should only be rerun under the same conditions as 1), but these dependencies seem to be hard-wired in Xcode...

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Not a solution but: the best way is to open a brand new project. Use Apple's default settings. Then archive, and inspect. This is your baseline.  Then incrementally make tiny changes. Document your build settings along with the outcome. Then commit that. Then make another change, document, commit. Compare with baseline. That's what I'm doing right now inspect some stuff...